# FullCalendar TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I was trying to put FullCalendar 2.1.1 but it is not working:

```html
<link href='/css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='/css/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='/css/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='/js/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='/js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='/js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      defaultDate: '2014-09-12',
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events               
    });

  });
</script>
```

When I go to try open it I get the following errors:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list ..."'").replace(/"/g,""").replace(/\n/g,"")}function P(t){returnt.replace(/


TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function    
eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
```

I have followed the Basic Usage Documentation but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like `fullcalendar.min.js` is minified incorrectly. Try [CDN version](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.js) instead first; if it works, just download it and replace the existing script with the copy.

Comment: it did the trick , thanks alot

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think you have problem with js try the below urls it may solve your problems,

```
<script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultDate: '2014-09-12',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        });
    });
</script>
```

If the above code works then download the js files used in script tag

Comment: Still not going error :: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/fullcalendar.min.js/"
/js/ful...min.js/
TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function
 

eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

Answer (score 20):

I also had same problem and it was because the HTML jQuery file was loading twice, hence it was giving me error.

Comment: Thanks, same thing was happening to me. jQuery was being loaded in a page view and again in a partial with a form.

Answer (score 15):

I've solved the problem simply changing order of my scripts. You must be set:
`moment.min.js` after `jquery.min.js` look this:

```
<script src='/js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='/js/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='/js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 6):

For anyone coming across this, there was only one solution working for me. I'm using webpack to compile my scripts and nothing was working for me, no matter what order I had `require('fullcalendar')` placed in my main.js file.

I had to downgrade to version `3.4.0`. It instantly solved the problem.

```
npm install --save fullcalendar@3.4.0
```

Comment: Thanks!  My Laravel installation with fullcalendar v3.9 was working fine before. But when I installed it today its not working anymore. Can anyone explain why it's happening?

Answer (score 3):

If using ES6 syntax, just add this at the start of your file:

```
import "fullcalendar";
```

Comment: Assuming you already have it in package.json, otherwise you have to also run `npm install "fullcalendar" --save`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I used **sitemesh** and decorators.

the problem solved when I injected the JS script's links **twice** both in the decorator and the webpage!

**The order is important too** ,**use following order** :

```
<script src="../../resource/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../resource/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../resource/dist/js/demo.js"></script>
<script src="../../resource/bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="../../resource/bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

(fullcalendar v5.5.0)

Seems fullCalendar() is not available anymore(not 100% sure).
I wanted to refresh when onchange event so I tried below first,

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEventSources', sources);
```

but got the same error message as above ( ~ not a function)
tried all answers on google but not for me.
finally below solved my problem.

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var newSource = {
          url: myUrl,
          type: 'POST',
          extraParams: {
               myParam: newParam
          }
    }
    
    // remove original source
    var orgSource = calendar.getEventSources();
    orgSource[0].remove();
    
    // add new source
    // new events will be immediately fetched from this source 
    // and placed on the calendar.
    calendar.addEventSource(newSource);
    
    // this is not working
    //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEventSources', newSource);
}
```

please also check below official site:

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEventSource

Comment: Thanks buddy tried every solution on the internet but in the end, your solution works fine. I was using CDN not sure if it is a problem with CDN or something else.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue when working with node version 14. Use node version 15 to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to the party but I was having a similar issue and I resolved it.

The versions that I was using in my **Angular 6 Project** were:

```
@angular/animations": "^6.0.9",
"@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
"@angular/common": "^6.0.9",
"@angular/compiler": "^6.0.9",
"@angular/core": "^6.0.9",
"fullcalendar": "^3.10.1",
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
.....
```

I changed the version for fullcalendar to **3.9.0** along with jquery to **^3.4.1** and it happily resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why, but none of the answers in this thread solved my (pretty much same) problem. I only managed to do with:

```
$('.fc-timeGridDay-button').click();
```

Sorry if its not the coolest solution, but I can't loose one more day banging my head against the wall :(