# fullcalendar not a function (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, calendar, fullcalendar

I try to use this plugin

[Plugin](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/)

Here is my code in View

```
  <link href="~/Content/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>

 <div id="calendar" style="height: 80%; width: 100%">

        </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                defaultDate: '2014-09-12',
                editable: true,
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            });
        });
</script>
```

But when I run website I have this error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument. (Index:134)
>       at j (fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/jquery.min.js:2)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/jquery.min.js:2)
>       at Function.ready (fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/jquery.min.js:2)
>       at HTMLDocument.J (fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/jquery.min.js:2)

How I can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Tried the following and its working fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="calendar" style="height: 80%; width: 100%">

</div>

<script src="http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultDate: '2014-09-12',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true 
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Make sure you are not loading two versions of jquery? Btw you are using quite an old version of fullcalendar.

Answer (score 0):

Although you should not really use the fullcalendar.io site as a CDN - it's not intended as one and there's no guarantee given that the files will remain in place, nonetheless it should work with the links you've given:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: '2014-09-12',
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>

<div id="calendar" style="height: 80%; width: 100%">

</div>
```

Note that I've used https instead of http mainly because SO is https and you can't link to a http resource from a https page. It's not impossible you have got the same problem. Also note I've used the CSS from fullCalendar rather than the local reference in your example (because obviously I can't access that).

Also check your page that your links really are correct (you can see any that haven't loaded properly by looking in your browser's network tab) and ensure you haven't loaded any of the same libraries more than once, or anything like that.

There's no obvious reason why the code in your example shouldn't work, so something else along the lines I've outlined above is almost certainly interfering.

P.S. As a longer term solution I'd recommend using the files at https://cdnjs.com/libraries/fullcalendar in your site, as these are guaranteed not to change, and as a proper CDN it will have sufficient bandwidth etc. You can also find the momentJS and jQuery libraries on the same site.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me. Moment.js is required i believe.
[FullCalendar TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252938/fullcalendar-typeerror-fullcalendar-is-not-a-function/39108519)

- Install moment.js from nuget or add manually.
- Call moment.js before fullcalendar.js.
- Ensure you are calling the js files in order:

  1. Jquery
  2. Jquery-UI
  3. Moment.js
  4. fullcalendar.js