# Fullcalendar refetchEventSources isn't called

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm using [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io) to render some events in a more pretty fashion.

I also want to have some filters.

```
jQuery('#some_id').change(function () {

 jQuery('#events').fullCalendar('refetchEventSources', {
        url: '/myfeed.php',
        color: 'yellow',   // an option!
        textColor: 'black' // an option!
    });
});
```

As far as I can tell, according to the documentation, it should work fine

Documentation in question:

- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/refetchEventSources/
- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/

However, the event is not triggered at all. The 'change' functions works as expected.

At this point I'm not sure if I'm doing anything wrong or this method has been deprecated.

Do note that the second parameter in the `fullCalendar` has placeholder variables. I've tried with actual variables, the results are the same.

Any pointing in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A stab in the dark: You don't happen to have a `refetchEventSources` declared elsewhere? which might mess up the Fullcalendar event scheme?

Comment: I'm not aware of another `refetchEventSources`. I've done a full search in the project and a search in the minimised javascript file. Mine and the default one that's in the fullcalendar.js are the only ones.

Comment: can you see the relevant ajax request running in your browser's network tab? Or just nothing happens? If nothing happens, check if your jquery selector (eventsPartyLiteCalendar) definitely correct? And fullCalendar is already initialised by the time this event runs? Sorry for the obvious questions but need to rule everything out.

Comment: I'm absolutely sure the selector is correct. I've tried with various other methods from the calendar(for example [refetchEvents](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/refetchEvents/)) on the same selector and they worked without any hickups. It's just that this event doesn't seem to run.

Comment: does it work if you try it outside the "change" event? And you didn't answer my points about the ajax call. Are you sure the ajax call never happens? Or does it happen, but fail?

Comment: Just tried it, the event doesn't seem to work...I think it may have been removed(?). Although they don't mention it being removed in their docs.

Comment: if the method didn't exist you'd likely get an error in the console. Have you checked for this? You keep saying "the event doesn't work" (what event, I thought we were testing it _without_ the change event?) but  you don't answer my question about what's in the network tab. Also, what version of fullCalendar are you using? As per the docs you need 2.8 or above to use refetchEventSources.

Comment: I'm using v3.4.0. However, I did found an issue on the project's git. [Here](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3551). Long story short. I think my code is wrong. But I'm not sure where exactly. When I say `event` I mean `refetchEventSources`. My network tab remains the same with or without the `change` event.

Comment: does an eventsource with that URL already exist in your fullCalendar config? Could you use the ID of the existing event source instead and see if that works? That issue you referenced was closed as invalid, and was related to the request sending a stale value (because of OP's misunderstanding of how JS works), not that it didn't send the ajax request at all.

Answer (score 1):

*** tested only for v5.5.0 ***

not working refetchEventSources as well.

below worked for me.

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var newSource = {
          url: myUrl,
          type: 'POST',
          extraParams: {
               myParam: newParam
          }
    }
    
    // remove original source
    var orgSource = calendar.getEventSources();
    orgSource[0].remove();
    
    // add new source
    // new events will be immediately fetched from this source 
    // and placed on the calendar.
    calendar.addEventSource(newSource);
    
    // this is not working
    //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEventSources', newSource);
}
```

above code is from my answer for the other question below.

[FullCalendar TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252938/fullcalendar-typeerror-fullcalendar-is-not-a-function/65403678#65403678)

also, below methods in the official site were helpful for me.
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEventSources

- Calendar getEventSources
- Calendar getEventSourceById
- Calendar addEventSource
- Calendar refetchEvents
- EventSource refetch
- EventSource remove