# Fullcalendar JavaScript not running in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, fullcalendar

I have been trying to fic this issue with my application for a few weeks now with no luck at all. I have tried multiple approaches which have all failed. If you could have a look at the code below and see where the issue is as I cannot find it.

I am using Node.js with Express, Handlebars and MongoDb for the application.

```js
app.js

// Bring in packages
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const jquery = require('jquery');
const moment = require('moment');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const passport = require('passport');

const app = express();

// Load routes
const webapp = require('./routes/webapp');

// Passport config
require('./config/passport')(passport);

// Db config
const db = require('./config/database');

// Map global promise - get rid of warning
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

// Connect to Mongoose
mongoose.connect(db.mongoURI, {
    useMongoClient: true
  })
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected...'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

// Load user model
require('./models/Users');
const User = mongoose.model('users');

// Handlebars Middleware - https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
  defaultLayout: 'main'
}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// Body Parser Middleware - https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Static folder middleware
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/modules', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')))

// Method override middleware - https://github.com/expressjs/method-override
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

// Express-session middleware - https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

// Connect-flash middleware - https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash
app.use(flash());

// Passport middleware - http://passportjs.org/docs
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Global variables
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
  res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  next();
});


webapp.js

const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const passport = require('passport');
const jquery = require('jquery');
const moment = require('moment');
const router = express.Router();

// Load Helper
const {
  ensureAuthenticated
} = require('../helpers/auth');

// Load user model
require('../models/Users');
const User = mongoose.model('users');

//App schedules route
router.get('/schedules', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.render('webapp/schedules');
});
```

```html
main.handlebars

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
  <link href="css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Link and script for calendar -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css" />
  <script src="../modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../modules/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
      })

    });
  </script>

  <title>Workmate</title>
</head>

schedules.handlebars

<div id='calendar'></div>
```

When this code runs the page shows up blank other than the navbar and I know its rendering right because if I insert a head tag it appears. I've looked and the developer options on chrome and get this error.

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:5000/webapp/schedules:75:20)
at l (http://localhost:5000/modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:29375)
at c (http://localhost:5000/modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:29677) undefined
```

Thanks for all your help in advance.

Comment: I believe this is a jquery library loading issue which can be fixed reordering.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252938/fullcalendar-typeerror-fullcalendar-is-not-a-function

Comment: @FaysalAhmed there's nothing wrong with the order in which the JS files are loaded in the code above. More likely the file simply doesn't exist in that location. OP should check their network tab to see whether fullcalendar.js is loaded successfully or not.

Comment: I've figured out the issue thanks to your help. Appreciate it guys

Comment: how resolved the problem? please

Comment: I didn't get it resolved

Comment: Check the working example here:
https://therichpost.com/nodejs-fullcalendar-working-example