# jQuery and Bootstrap dialog not coming up

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, razor, fullcalendar

Currently have a FullCalendar Application which keeps tracks of appointments. Recently changed the layout around which somehow helped get my dialog working. So whenever I click an appointment on the calendar, it comes up with the details in a dialog.

I have switched some things around and now it doesn't work, coming up on Internet Explorer with `Unhandled exception at line 214, column 25 in http://localhost:9755/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=/Appointments/Calendar
0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'modal' occurred`

I'm 99% sure its something in my layout page that I have put in.

Been wrecking my head for so long. Here's my Calendar Page:

```
    <div id="calendar"></div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><span id="eventTitle"></span></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button id="btnDelete" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Remove
                </button>
                <button id="btnEdit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" style="margin-right:5px;">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit
                </button>
                <p id="pDetails"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@*<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />*@
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />

@section Scripts{
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var events = [];
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Appointments/GetEvents",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                        events.push({
                            details: v.DetailsOfAppointment,
                            date: moment(v.DateOfAppointment),
                            room: v.RoomType,
                            confirmed: v.Confirmed,
                            colour: v.ThemeColour,
                            church: v.Church.Name,
                            parishAdminName: v.Admins.AdministratorName,
                            parishAdminUser: v.Admins.AdminUsername,
                            parishAdminId: v.Admins.AdministratorId,
                            fee: v.Fee,
                            id: v.AppointmentId
                        });

                    })
                     GenerateCalender(events);   
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert("failed");
                    console.log(error);
                }
            })

            function GenerateCalender(events) {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    contentHeight: 500,
                    defaultDate: new Date(),
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
                    },
                    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
                    eventLimit: true,
                    eventColor: events.ThemeColour,
                    events: events,
                    eventRender: function (event, element) {
                        if (event.fee == null) {
                            if (event.confirmed == false) {
                                element.css('background-color', '#FF0000');
                                element.css('border-color', '#FF0000');
                            }
                            else {
                                element.css('background-color', '#008000');
                                element.css('border-color', '#008000');
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            element.css('background-color', '#0000FF');
                            element.css('border-color', '#0000FF');

                        }
                    },
                    eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                        $('#myModal #details').text(calEvent.details);
                        var $details = $('<div/>');

                        if (calEvent.fee != null) {
                            $details.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Date of Ceremony : </b>' + calEvent.date.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                        }
                        else {
                            $details.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Date of Appointment : </b>' + calEvent.date.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                        }
                        if (calEvent.end != null) {
                            $details.append($('<p/>').html('<b>End:</b>' + calEvent.end.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                        }
                        $details.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Details : </b>' + calEvent.details));
                        $details.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Church Name : </b>' + calEvent.church));
                        if (calEvent.fee == null) {
                            if (calEvent.room != null) {
                                $details.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Room : </b>' + calEvent.room));
                            }
                            else {
                                $details.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Room Not Confirmed'));
                            }
                        }


                        $details.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Parish Admin : </b>' + calEvent.parishAdminName));
                        if (calEvent.confirmed == true)
                        {
                            $details.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Status : Confirmed </b>'));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $details.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Status : Not Confirmed </b>'));
                        }
                        $('#myModal #pDetails').empty().html($details);

                        $('#myModal').modal();
                    }

                })
            }
        })
    </script>
}
```

And my layout page, which I think the problem is in.

```
<head>

@Styles.Render("~/Content/Site.css")

@Styles.Render("~/Content/jquery.datetimepicker.css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/fullcalendar.css")

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Here's my google snippet after I used F12
[image]

Comment: this error probably indicates that `$('#myModal')` isn't matching any element.. you can make sure that  the element with the id `myModal` exists by printing `$('#myModal').length` to the console and seeing if its different than zero

Comment: @OsvaldoMaria I'm using the $('#myModal').length and nothing is appearing in the console, does it matter if I'm using chrome or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**I think there is no use to include the script twice. So Remove the script from layout page**

Comment: After I add these, the calendar doesn't appear. I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function

Comment: Are you Include these script on top of the page??

Comment: I have them declared in my layout page. The calendar page has the layout page declared also

Comment: I think there is no use to include that script in layout page. I am not sure just try it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252938/fullcalendar-typeerror-fullcalendar-is-not-a-function if you still cant get the apt answer have a look at this