# jQuery & Bootstrap scripts messing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Currently, have a web app for appointments. I had a question answered around last week at the following link: [jQuery and Bootstrap dialog not coming up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49637574/jquery-and-bootstrap-dialog-not-coming-up/49649630?noredirect=1#comment86309179_49649630)

I got this working. However, I just noticed that this messes up my NavBar that is stored in my layout file. On any other page, the NavBar works, but on the Calendar page it doesn't respond. The only thing I can think of is the scripts are clashing.

I tried taking them out of my calendar page but this causes my calendar to not pop up with a dialog. I must be doing something wrong here but I honestly don't know.

Here is my layout file's scripts.

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/Site.css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/jquery.datetimepicker.css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/fullcalendar.css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

My Calendar File Scripts:

```
@section Scripts{
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    }
```

If more code is needed, I can supply it.

**EDIT** Image of my console after I load Calendar:
[image]

**EDIT 2** Image of my console after I load Calendar after removing one instance of Jquery:
[image]

Comment: any errors? whats happening? whats differnet on the pages that it does work and the ones it doesnt

Comment: It looks like you're including jquery and bootstrap in both places. Loading these twice can cause issues.

Comment: @JoeWarner it works on every page except the Calendar page

Comment: @RyanGibbs I know, but if I remove it in the Calendar page it throws an exception saying Modal not defined

Comment: Are your calendar scripts section loaded after your layout? It could be that it's trying to load them before jquery is loaded.

Comment: Honestly at a loss. Got it working with a dialog and didn't think much of it @RyanGibbs

Comment: Looking back at your other question I think you're still fighting the same issue. It's a matter of dependencies. Bootstrap requires jquery, so jquery has to load prior to bootstrap. So you need to remove them from the calendar scripts section, then make sure the layout portion loads (is higher on the page) than the scripts section of your calendar page.

Comment: @RyanGibbs I tried and no joy, dunno what to do

Comment: Two other things I would suggest then; Try moving all your Calendar scripts to your layout file script section just to see if that's the issue. Also, you might try moving modernizr as well. Also, if you look at the network tab of the developer console, you can see the order scripts load. That might give you a hint to the problem.

Comment: @RyanGibbs added pic to question

Comment: So you've got 3 different jquery files loading there. Figure out where those top two local files are being called and comment them out, that way you'll just have the cdn version.

Comment: @RyanGibbs put up another picture but still having same problem

Comment: Let's move to a chat to avoid a novel of back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had an error on my Layout Page that was causing hassle.

The scripts section weren't being rendered as I had `RenderSection("Scripts", false)`

Removed the scripts section and that and the error went away!